# Eliminar de una lista y recargar con 'this.forceUpdate();'

Tags: nodejs, lista, reactjs, update, component

estoy eliminando usuarios de una lista que implementé usando 'Ant Design' en React, los datos de esta lista de usuarios los obtengo mediante una api en express, pero no veo los cambios hasta que recargo el navegador con 'F5', en mi caso no me es necesario modificar el estado ni comparar props ni nada similar, una vez que elimino el usuario simplemente creo necesitar recargar el componente para obtener la lista una vez más pero con el usuario eliminado. Dada esta situación pensé en una solución utilizando 'this.forceUpdate();' con la idea de hacer las cosas más sencillas. El código no me devuelve error alguno y entonces no sé si es que se me está escapando algo ya que nunca me he enfrentado a una situación similar. Adjunto debajo el código de mi componente en React.  Gracias de antemano!

```js
//mi componente en React
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { getAll, dell } from '../FetchServer';

import { List, Avatar, Button, Skeleton, message } from 'antd';

import GoToHome from './GoToHome';
import GoToRegister from './GoToRegister';
import UpdateUserModal from './UpdateUserModal';

class Users extends Component {

 state = {
  initLoading: true,
  loading: false,
  data: [],
  list: [],
 };

 fakeDataUrl = async () => {
  const aux = await getAll();
  return aux['data'];
 };

 async componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
   initLoading: false,
   data: this.fakeDataUrl(),
   list: await this.fakeDataUrl()
  });
 }

 verifyRoute = () => {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('token')) {
   return this.props.history.push('/login');
  }
 };

 recargar = () => {
  this.forceUpdate()
 }

 render() {
  this.verifyRoute();
  const { initLoading, loading, list } = this.state;
  const loadMore =
   !initLoading && !loading ? (
    <div
     style={{
      textAlign: 'center',
      marginTop: 12,
      height: 32,
      lineHeight: '32px'
     }}
    >
     <Button onClick={this.onLoadMoreConsoleEstado}>loading more</Button>
    </div>
   ) : null;

  return (
   <div>
    <GoToHome />
    <GoToRegister />
    <List
     className="demo-loadmore-list"
     loading={initLoading}
     itemLayout="horizontal"
     loadMore={loadMore}
     dataSource={list}
     renderItem={(item) => (
      <List.Item actions={[
       <UpdateUserModal item={item} />,
       <a onClick={() => {
        dell(item);//aquí elimino el usuario
        message.success('Usuario eliminado');//aquí envío un mensaje de confirmación
        this.forceUpdate();//entonces aquí intento recargar, pero no funciona
       }}>eliminar</a>
      ]}>
       <Skeleton avatar title={false} loading={item.loading} active>
        <List.Item.Meta
         avatar={
          <Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />
         }
         title={<a href="https://ant.design">{item.nickname}</a>}
         description="Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team"
        />
        <div>content</div>
       </Skeleton>
      </List.Item>
     )}
    />
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Users;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es normal que no se actualice, porque no le estás diciendo que se actualice, y no necesitas llamar al método `forceUpdate`.

Se entiende que tus funciones `getAll` y `dell` hacen una llamada a un servidor y retornan una promesa. Como no tengo acceso a tu código de la función `dell` no sé como funciona internamente, pero lo que te puedo explicar es que si tu eliminas algo en tu `backend` no tiene que ver con tu `frontend` en este caso, así que si lo eliminas allá, no se elimina acá y tienes que eliminarlo nuevamente. Para ello debes hacer esto:

```
<a onClick={async () => {
  await dell(item);  // si retornas la promesa, es mucho mejor hacerlo con un `.then`
  let listCopy = [ ...this.state.list ];
  let _index = listCopy.findIndex(i => i.nickname === item.nickname);
  _index >= 0 && listCopy.splice(_index, 1);
  this.setState({ list: listCopy }, () => message.success('Usuario eliminado'));
}}>eliminar</a>
```

Como puedes ver lo que estoy haciendo es copiar la lista de elementos cuando hago esto: `let listCopy = [ ...this.state.list ]`, esto porque la recomendación que propone react es no modificar el estado directamente, y al utilizar la función `splice` para eliminar el objeto, estamos modificando el objeto. Luego buscamos el index del objeto para saber cual se debe eliminar en la lista, y en la última línea con el `setState` volvemos a recargar la lista de items pero ahora si excluyendo el que se eliminó.

Cualquier pregunta o duda que tengas, no dudes en comentar

Comment: muchas gracias German, una vez más tu explicación me ayudó a resolver mi problema